# Less than & greater than calculations in awk assistance

Tags: shell, awk

Thanks for reading this.

**Objective:** 
Obtain cost of each company's total.
brand dogs > 200, then count * 0.03 else count * 0.05

So 'yhaoo office' total would be $9.00:

```
300 * 0.03 = 9.00
```

And if that was easy...if the total is less than $5, what's the difference?
Looking at yahoo bar:

```
60 * .05 = 3 & 5-3 = 2
```

```
cat /tmp/tmp.9VvVu4MT5Y
mid,company,brand,count
455,stackoverflow,inet,18
8484,reddit,neti,13
1257,google,marks,50
4780,yahoo bar,dogs,60
4789,oohay park,dogs,100
8754,yhaoo office,dogs,300
```

Comment: What's your expected output? There is no column 5 in your input..

Comment: The multiplication of count * .03 or .05 depending on the count.

Comment: is my answer match your needs?

Comment: Yes,  Avinash Raj, you did very well with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{if($3=="dogs" && $4>200) $5=$4*0.03; if($3=="dogs" && $4<200) $5=$4*0.05;}1' file
mid,company,brand,count
455,stackoverflow,inet,18
8484,reddit,neti,13
1257,google,marks,50
4780,yahoo bar,dogs,60,3
4789,oohay park,dogs,100,5
8754,yhaoo office,dogs,300,9
```

Comment: Here's what I did for subtraction from fiedld $5:


`awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR>1{if($3=="dogs" && $5<20) $6=20-$5; if($3=='dogs' && $5>20) $6=0;}1'`